# How can I prevent duplicate Emails from being posted into the Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

```
function grabDover() {
  const dover = GmailApp.search('has:attachment label:"1st Choice Auto Dover Scans"');
  const doverSheet = ss.getSheetByName('1st Choice Auto Dover Scans');
  dover.forEach(thread => {
    const messages = thread.getMessages();
    messages.forEach(message => {
      const messageid = message.getId();
      const attachments = message.getAttachments();
      const date = message.getDate();
      const subject = message.getSubject();
      const url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#label/' + messageid;
      attachments.forEach(attachment => {
        Logger.log(date);
        const array = [attachment.getName(), date, url, messageid];
        doverSheet.appendRow(array);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

I have this script that pulls email attachments from Gmail, based on label names and soon to be a time trigger, and I can not figure out how to prevent duplicate email attachments from being pulled.

I am trying to have the script, cross check the messageIds that are being pulled from Gmail into the sheet, so no duplicate emails are being posted into the sheet.
I have the messageid in a array already. I have tried doing it with a scriptproperties method and it did not work or I was doing it wrong.

I can get it to work via google spread sheet formula but It wont work for my exact use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the values from `const dover = GmailApp.search('has:attachment label:"1st Choice Auto Dover Scans"');`.
- When you retrieve the values from `dover`, you want to check the message IDs and want to put only the values when the message IDs are not found.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2018/10/12/benchmark-reading-and-writing-spreadsheet-using-google-apps-script/)
- Message IDs are not checked.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function grabDover() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const dover = GmailApp.search('has:attachment label:"1st Choice Auto Dover Scans"');
  const doverSheet = ss.getSheetByName('1st Choice Auto Dover Scans');
  const lastRow = doverSheet.getLastRow();
  const currentMessageIds = [...new Set(doverSheet.getDataRange().getValues().map(([, , , d]) => d))];
  const values = dover.reduce((ar, thread) => {
    thread.getMessages().forEach(message => {
      const messageid = message.getId();
      if (!currentMessageIds.includes(messageid)) {
        const attachments = message.getAttachments();
        const date = message.getDate();
        Logger.log(date);
        const url = 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#label/' + messageid;
        ar = [...ar, ...attachments.map(attachment => [attachment.getName(), date, url, messageid])];
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  doverSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, when the message IDs in `dover` are not found in the current sheet "1st Choice Auto Dover Scans", the values are put into the sheet.

#### Note:

- In this modified script, it supposes that from your script, the message IDs are put into column "D". Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)